# Capture output from a shell command with babel in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I want to know about my networking hardware.

```
lspci | grep -i net
```

From the terminal, this command gives the following output:

> > 00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
> >     02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)

But when I try running this from org-mode through a babel source block I get no output.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
lspci | grep -i net
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

What gives?  How can I get the same output I got from the terminal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do get results, only not handled properly (most likely temporarily displayed in the minibuffer).

Add `:results output replace` after `#+begin_src sh`, as a **header argument** (to override default values), to have the **output** (re)**placed** in your org-mode buffer. All its possible values are described [here in the Manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html#Results-of-Evaluation).

Comment: Adding `:results replace` was the first thing I tried.  Unfornately, I didn't see any change in output.  Reading [the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/System_002dwide-header-arguments.html#System_002dwide-header-arguments) I saw that `:results replace` was the default value anyway.

Comment: @wdkrnls: try `results: output replace`, and `results: append`, maybe also. Check they're not output elsewhere in the buffer, if you have a `#+name` (by executing in a blank org file). (also the mistake I usually do is to forget the plural to resultS)