# Capturing the output of "diff" with org-babel

Tags: emacs, sh, org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to capture the output of `diff` with org-babel, but for some reason it's not working. For the files

1

```
a b c
```

2

```
a c b
```

`diff 1 2` called from the command line returns

```
1c1
< a b c
---
> a c b
```

But with org-babel, nothing:

```
#+begin_src sh                                                                                                                                                 
diff 1 2                                                                                                                                                       
#+end_src                                                                                                                                                      

#+RESULTS:
```

The minibuffer reads "Code block produced no output". The org-babel error output window is empty. Other commands such as `ls` show the output as expected. I'm not familiar with org-babel.

I tried using `:results output verbatim`, no changes. I also tried using `:results output replace` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771642/capture-output-from-a-shell-command-with-babel-in-org-mode). Didn't help.

- Emacs version is 24.4.1 (on Debian jessie)
- Org-mode version is 8.2.10

Comment: When diff finds that two files differ it returns with a non-zero exit code. org-babel seems to assume that if a block returns a non-zero exit code then the execution has failed and org-babel chokes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem (on OSX).

The strange thing is that executing the babel block will open the *Org-babel Error Output* buffer, as if something were going to STDERR.

If you add any other output after diff, results will display OK. For example,

```
#+begin_src sh :results output
diff 1 2
echo
#+end_src
```

If you force diff's results to stdout, results will also display:

```
#+begin_src sh :results output
diff 1 2 | cat
#+end_src
```

Comment: @Alex Did you ever submit that bug? If so, I'll add a patch to it - if not, I'll submit my own, with a patch.

Comment: @AaronMiller I don't remember. I'd suggest you add your own.

Comment: @AaronMiller: Did something happen with this issue? I just got the same problem, and the same workaround applies.

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername Never had a chance to follow up.

Comment: 3 years and the bug is still out there.

Comment: 5 years and a couple months

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `org-babel` doesn't like it when the return code isn't `0`. That's why the various solutions work. Adding another command uses means that the overall error code of the block is success.  Similarly piping into `cat` makes the pipeline return the error code of `cat`. Yet another way of eating the error condition is:

```
  diff 1 2 || true
```