# Can't capture the output of rg/ag/pt with org-babel on OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to capture the output of rg but I'm getting no output (I'm getting the message "Code block produced no output" in the minibuffer.

I've also tried `ag` and `pt` which don't work either. It works with grep but this is too slow for my use-case.

Example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
mkdir -p myproject
pushd myproject
echo "something" > something.txt
rg something
popd
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

I've tried the solutions from these similar questions, but they're not working here:

- [Capturing the output of "diff" with org-babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304469/capturing-the-output-of-diff-with-org-babel)
- [Capture output from a shell command with babel in org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771642/capture-output-from-a-shell-command-with-babel-in-org-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1)